# How to append elements at the end of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, append

I am wondering, how do I append an element to the end of an ArrayList in Java? Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Stack {

    private ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator();

    private void push(){
        String random = rsg.randomStringGenerator();
        ArrayList.add(random);
    }

}
```

`randomStringGenerator` is a method which generates a random String.

I basically want to always append the random string at the end of the ArrayList, much like a stack (Hence the name "push").

Comment: Use `stringList.add`. And it's "appended" to the end..

Comment: What do you think this - `ArrayList.add(random);` will do? To which arraylist will it add?

Comment: If you want something that works like a stack, why not use a Stack?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist He's trying to implement a `Stack` that's backed by an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @RohitJain I see now that it was wrong, I am new to programming and thought that you have to use the method "add" on an ArrayList, because the method belongs to that class, and then I thought that if you write "random" it will attach the string "random" to the ArrayList, but of course, that makes little sense because how would the computer know to add it to "stringList", right?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am doing this for a school exercise, and they want us to implement the stack ourselves, in order to get a better understanding of what a stack is

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thank you!! Of course, I stupidly got confused by that you have to create an object of a class type and then use the methods on the object, and not use methods directly on the class...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here is the syntax, along with some other methods you might find useful:

```
    //add to the end of the list
    stringList.add(random);

    //add to the beginning of the list
    stringList.add(0,  random);

    //replace the element at index 4 with random
    stringList.set(4, random);

    //remove the element at index 5
    stringList.remove(5);

    //remove all elements from the list
    stringList.clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and just passed the end of the array to the `ArrayList.add()` index param like so:

```
public class Stack {

    private ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator();

    private void push(){
        String random = rsg.randomStringGenerator();
        stringList.add(stringList.size(), random);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to make an answer of my own. here is another way to do this if you "really" want to add to the end of the list instead of using `list.add(str)` you can do it this way, but I don't recommend.

```
 String[] items = new String[]{"Hello", "World"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(list, items);
        int endOfList = list.size();
        list.add(endOfList, "This goes end of list");
        System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(list));
```

*this is the 'Compact' way of adding the item to the end of list.
here is a safer way to do this, with null checking and more.*

```
String[] items = new String[]{"Hello", "World"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(list, items);
        addEndOfList(list, "Safer way");
        System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(list));

 private static void addEndOfList(List<String> list, String item){
            try{
                list.add(getEndOfList(list), item);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }

   private static int getEndOfList(List<String> list){
        if(list != null) {
            return list.size();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Heres another way to add items to the end of list, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;


public class matrixcecil {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Integer> k1=new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
        k1.add(23);
        k1.add(10);
        k1.add(20);
        k1.add(24);
        int i=0;
        while(k1.size()<10){
            if(i==(k1.get(k1.size()-1))){

            }
             i=k1.get(k1.size()-1);
             k1.add(30);
             i++;
             break;
        }
        System.out.println(k1);
    }

}
```

I think this example will help you for better solution.